# Certificate recognized by the driver is not appearing in OpenOffice

Tags: firefox, libreoffice

I'm trying to get a token for digital signature working on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I've installed its [drivers](https://www.sitepro.com.ar/web/preguntas-frecuentes/instalacion-safenet-etoken-5110-5300/) and added the certificates manually in firefox, but when trying to sign a pdf openOffice (v. 7.3.7.2.) won't find any certificate.
I've tried whatever forum I've found with different solutions (like checking the [trust of the authorities](https://forum.openoffice.org/es/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=9816), or editing mozilla [path to the certificate](https://forum.openoffice.org/es/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=14298)).
I've installed the certificates in both thunderbird and firefox (123.0.1 (64-bit)).

The driver is recognizing the token and the certificate.
[image]

But the certificate is not in OpenOffice:
[image]

And the certificates has been added manually into firefox:
[image]

I've followed [the guide here](http://gnulinux.unp.edu.ar/index.php/2021/09/14/firma-digital-en-gnu-linux-ubuntu-20-04/) to the letter, but I fear that there's a missing step somewhere.

I did initialize the token, and the password is correct.